# How to modify a 2d tensor to 3d in libtorch?

Tags: pytorch, libtorch

I have a 2d array vector<vector>, I have coverted it to tensor, but how to modify the dimension of the tensor, I want to modify the dimension from 2d to 3d?

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> voice(434, std::vector<float>(80))
ifstream fp("data.txt");
if (! fp) {
    cout << "Error, file couldn't be opened" << endl; 
    return 1; 
}    
for(int i=0;i<80;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<434;j++)
    {
        if ( ! fp ) 
        {
            std::cout << "read error" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        fp >> voice[i][j]
    }
}

auto options = torch::TensorOptions().dtype(at::kDouble);
auto tensor = torch::zeros({80,434}, options);
for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
    tensor.slice(0, i,i+1) = torch::from_blob(vect[i].data(), {434}, options);
```

Now the `tensor` is 80 * 434, how can I add one dimension in this `tensor` to 3d, I want 1 * 80 * 434

Comment: How does your 2D tensor look like? Give a sample of it. Also, provide how do you want your tensor to look like?

Comment: @ShaidaMuhammad Now the tensor is 80 * 434, I want 1 * 80 *434

Comment: added the answer already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auto tensor = torch::zeros({80,434}, options);
```

followed by this line

```
auto tensor = tensor.view({1, 80, 434});
```

I would recommend to create another variable instead of `tensor` in the second line, like:

```
auto transformed_tensor = tensor.view({1, 80, 434});
```